# How to setup syntax highlighting for interfaces and delegates in Visual Studio 11 Beta?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

In VS2010 this types has been highlighted, but now it looks like this:

[image: highlighting example]

Comment: There's no Visual Studio 2012 yet. You can file a bug report for the Visual Studio 11 **Beta** [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me...

[image: VS11 Beta Professional]

(That's using VS11 Beta, Professional edition.)

Look in Tools / Options / Fonts and Colors and find "User Types (interfaces)" and "User Types (delegate)". Both should default to Teal. If they're not, try changing them explicitly - or just hit the "Use defaults" button to reset *all* fonts and colors to the defaults.

Comment: thank you for you reply, to be honest in settings there is only User Types option, no separate for interfaces and delegates and it set to Teal, I have tried to set it explicity, but no effect, set to defaults also have no effect , I'm using VS11 Beta Ultimate, seems like this is a bug, i already submitted a report

Comment: @Alexander: If you haven't even got all the options, that sounds like the installation may be messed up... do you have another computer you could try installing it on to see?

Comment: no i can't, i asked some people, they don't have same problem but they using win7, i'm using win8 consumer preview, i will try to make clean install tomorrow

Comment: @Alexander: Ah, it would probably have been worth saying that before. I wonder if that's relevant.

Comment: it was a bug of installation really, reinstall on different Win8 solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VS2012. Here is how to fix it without re-installing:

Close all instances.
Delete the following registry entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FontAndColors
```

Reopen VS2012

The problem should be fixed.